# jQuery Undelegate from within the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I undelegate the #submit click event?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".agent img").click(function(){
                $(".agent-form").remove();
                var agentid = $(this).attr("alt"),
                    response = "<form method='post' action='' class='agent-form'><textarea placeholder='Your Comment' name='comment' id='comment'></textarea><input type='button' value='submit' id='submit' /></form>";
                $(response).hide().appendTo(this.parentNode).fadeIn();
                $(".agent").delegate("#submit","click",function(){
                    var message = $("#comment").val();
                    message = escape(message);
                    var dataString = "agent="+agentid+"&message="+message;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "includes/newcomment.asp",
                        data: dataString,
                        success: function(){
                            console.log(dataString);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

I want to undelegate all #submit click events that were created on previous .agent img clicks. The problem is that if the user clicks on an agent img then decides to click on another img the ajax submits to different datastrings.

Comment: Looks like the problem here is because of Duplicated ID's on the page.. try replacing them with classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [jQuery doc for `.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), you can use [`.undelegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/undelegate/) to remove an event handlers.

You don't show us your HTML, but this sounds more like you should just have one delegated event handler that is always there rather than creating one, removing one, creating another, etc...  You can store the agentid in the form element when you create it and then retrieve it upon the submit handler like this.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $(document).delegate("#submit", "click", function() {
            var message = $("#comment").val();
            message = escape(message);
            // get agentid for this form
            var agentid = $(this).closest("form").data("agentid");
            var dataString = "agent="+agentid+"&message="+message;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "includes/newcomment.asp",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(){
                    console.log(dataString);
                }
            });
        });

        $(".agent img").click(function(){
            $(".agent-form").remove();
            var agentid = $(this).attr("alt"),
            // build form HTML (embed agentid into it for later retrieval)
            var response = "<form method='post' action='' class='agent-form' data-agentid='" + agendid + "'><textarea placeholder='Your Comment' name='comment' id='comment'></textarea><input type='button' value='submit' id='submit' /></form>";
            $(response).hide().appendTo(this.parentNode).fadeIn();
        });
    });
```

Comment: I added an alternate implementation that just uses one lasting `.delegate()` handler rather than removing and recreating it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the .unbind() method of jQuery..

It's documented [Here](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

Basically..

```
$(".agent img").unbind("click");
```